# how to add average column along with total in group by rollup?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

i have 3 colmns as count,duration and percentage. i used rollup for grand total for count and duration but i want average of percentage column.

```
select to_char(anstime,'HH24'),
       count(anstime),
       sum(billdurtn),
       round((sum(billdurtn)/(30*3600*1))*100,2) 
from crm.t_ivr_detailed_logs 
where date(anstime)='2018-06-22' 
group by rollup(to_char(anstime,'HH24'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `round((sum(billdurtn)/(30*3600*1))*100,2)` with

```
avg(SELECT round((sum(billdurtn)/(30*3600*1))*100,2)
FROM crm.t_ivr_detailed_logs 
where date(anstime)='2018-06-22'
group by rollup(to_char(anstime,'HH24')))
```

.....